# WebGL: crashes 1% of the time

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

It seems that once every couple hundred times that I run my WebGL environment, I get this warning:

`Matrix3.getInverse(): can't invert matrix, determinant is 0`

This message will repeat every frame of rendering until the console says there are too many warning messages

Upon refreshing the page, it renders appropriately. It must render every time.

Another warning that is given when it does work (but not when it doesn't) is:

`THREE.WebGLProgram: gl.getProgramInfoLog()WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'vUv' not read by fragment shader`

But when it works it works totally good, and most of the time it does

Is there any advanced error reporting or anything I can do to help pinpoint what is causing the error and why it sometimes just doesn't work?

Some vague additional information: I am loading up a an OBJ, adding a reflection texture and then performing an animation.

P.S. the script breaking occurs right after the obj loads, and the obj is never shown on the screen, so it may be occurring before the animation, but the animation does begin as soon as the model is loaded so maybe not?

Please check out [Thoscene.com](http://thoscene.com) if you need more info.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Remove the animation. Provide the simplest live example you can to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Just a guess but you're probably getting a `NaN` in your math for some reason, most likely a bug where the code is using an uninitialized variable  that only gets used on a race condition or the code is downloading some data and parsing it incorrectly or it's bad data and it's not being 100% validated. That's just a guess. Put some code that checks the matrix for `NaN` in `getInverse` or wrap that in some code that checks for `NaN`.

Comment: Please check out Thoscene.com. Any help is appreciated